# How to get the information of RuntimeWarning in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, warnings

```
try:
   np.arccos(10)
except RuntimeWarning:
   print('error')enter code here
```

but nothing happens, I am a newer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cause a warning to raise an exception than you can use `warnings.simplefilter("error")` which will force the warning into an exception, e.g.:

```
In []:
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("error")
try:
    np.arccos(10)
except RuntimeWarning:
    print('error')

Out[]:
error
```

Alternative, you can record the warnings with `warnings.catch_warnings(record=True)` context manager:

```
In []:
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as ws:
    np.arccos(10)
for w in ws:
    print(w.message)

Out[]:
invalid value encountered in arccos
```